# Recyclerview not showing images getting from device media store- Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-recyclerview, imageview

I am trying to show all images in recyclerview after reading from device gallery, but recyclerview is not showing any images.

**MainActivity:**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        private lateinit var imageAdapter: ImageAdapter
        private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
        private val REQUEST = 112
    
        @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
            imageAdapter = ImageAdapter()
            checkPermission()
            val format = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")
            val strDate = format.format(Date())
            binding.btnDate.text = strDate
            val imgList = getImagesPath(this, strDate)
            prepareRecyclerView()
            setImageList(imgList)
    
        }
    
        private fun setImageList(imgList: ArrayList<String?>) {
            imageAdapter.setImageList(imgList as ArrayList<String>)
        }
    
        fun funclick(view: View) {
            pickDateTime()
        }
    
        private fun prepareRecyclerView() {
            binding.recyclerView.apply {
                layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 2, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
                adapter = imageAdapter
            }
        }
    
    
        private fun checkPermission() {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                )
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            )
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
                    REQUEST
                )
        }
    
        private fun pickDateTime() {
            val currentDateTime = Calendar.getInstance()
            val startYear = currentDateTime.get(Calendar.YEAR)
            val startMonth = currentDateTime.get(Calendar.MONTH)
            val startDay = currentDateTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    
            DatePickerDialog(
                this,
                DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { picker, year, month, day ->
                    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
                    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, picker.year)
                    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, picker.month)
                    calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, picker.dayOfMonth)
                    val format = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")
                    val strDate = format.format(calendar.getTime())
                    val imgList: ArrayList<String?> = getImagesPath(this, strDate)
                    setImageList(imgList)
                },
                startYear,
                startMonth,
                startDay
            ).show()
        }
    
    
        fun getImagesPath(activity: Activity, strDate: String): ArrayList<String?> {
            val listOfAllImages = ArrayList<String?>()
            val cursor: Cursor?
            val column_index_folder_name: Int
            var PathOfImage: String? = null
            val uri: Uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
            val projection = arrayOf<String>(
                MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME
            )
            cursor = activity.contentResolver.query(
                uri, projection, null,
                null, null
            )
            val column_index_data: Int = cursor!!.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA)
            column_index_folder_name = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME)
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                PathOfImage = cursor.getString(column_index_data)
                val file: File = File(PathOfImage)
                if (file.exists()) {
                    val date = file.lastModified()
                    val yourDate = Date(date)
                    val formatter: DateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")
                    val formattedDate: String = formatter.format(yourDate)
                    if (strDate.equals(formattedDate)) listOfAllImages.add(PathOfImage)
                }
                // listOfAllImages.add(PathOfImage)
            }
            return listOfAllImages
        }
    }
    
    ImageAdapter:
    class ImageAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ImageViewHolder>() {
        private var imgList: List<String> = ArrayList()
        // var actionMenu: (String) -> Unit = {}
    
        fun setImageList(imgCount: List<String>) {
            this.imgList = imgCount
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    
    
        inner class ImageViewHolder(val binding: ImageCardBinding) :
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
            init {
                binding.imgCategory.setOnClickListener {
                    // actionMenu.invoke(categoryList[position].strCategory)
                }
            }
        }
    
    
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ImageViewHolder {
            println("called1")
            return ImageViewHolder(ImageCardBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)))
        }
    
        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ImageViewHolder, position: Int) {
            println("called1")
            holder.binding.apply {
                text1.text = "sadasda"
             //   imgCategory.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgList[position]))
                Glide.with(holder.itemView)
                    .load(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .into(imgCategory)
            }
    
        }
    
        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return imgList.size
        }
    
    
    }
```

**activity_main.xml:**

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:onClick="funclick"
                android:text="@string/lbl_select_date"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/value_6"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btn_date" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

### ****image_card.xml****

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="190dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/value_10"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/value_10">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardview"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_category"
                android:layout_width="180dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="asdsad"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

MainActivity is sending image list to ImageAdapter. I am seeing images sent to adapter, but somehow recyclerview adapter is not showing. In ImageAdapter, onBindViewHolder, getItemCount is not getting called.

Comment: You should not add the path to the images list but the uri. You do not need a path at all. And mostly you are not permitted to read the path. But you can read the uri.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're facing might be related to incorrect layout inflation in the `onCreate` method of your `MainActivity`. You should use the `binding` variable to set the content view, as you have already inflated your layout using `binding`. Here's the corrected `onCreate` method:

```kotlin
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root) // Use binding.root to set the content view
    imageAdapter = ImageAdapter()
    checkPermission()
    val format = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")
    val strDate = format.format(Date())
    binding.btnDate.text = strDate
    val imgList = getImagesPath(this, strDate)
    prepareRecyclerView()
    setImageList(imgList)
}
```

This change ensures that your activity's content view is correctly set to the inflated layout from the binding object.

Additionally, make sure that the `ImageAdapter` is correctly associated with the `RecyclerView` in your layout XML (`activity_main.xml`). The `app:layoutManager` attribute should be set to `"androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"`, as you have defined it in your layout XML.

If the `onBindViewHolder` and `getItemCount` methods are still not being called, please ensure that you are setting the adapter to the `RecyclerView` in your `prepareRecyclerView` function, as you are already doing. If the issue persists, consider checking the `setImageList` method to ensure that it's correctly updating the data in the adapter.

If you've verified these points and are still facing issues, please check for any error messages in the logcat that might provide more information about what's going wrong.